# Why does Get-CimInstance CIM_LogicalDisk return two types?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

Why does `Get-CimInstance CIM_LogicalDisk` return both a `Win32_LogicalDisk` and a `Win32_MappedLogicalDisk`?

There is a Win32_MappedLogical disk CIM class, but there is no Cim_MappedLogicalDisk` class. Should there be?

In pwsh 6 there does not appear to be one either. There are no CIM cmdlets in pwsh 6 on Linux. Is CIM a Microsoft-only thing? I thought not.

```
C:>$Provider = Get-CimInstance CIM_LogicalDisk | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'W:' }

C:>$Provider.Count
2
```

Comment: `CIM` is a standard instrumentation "thing".  It applies to any computer.  The `Win32` classes are Microsoft's implementation of `CIM` known as `WMI`.  That being said, I'm unable to replicate what your question states.  Enumerating `CIM_LogicalDisk` just returns the one set of `Win32_LogicalDisk` class objects.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 do you have mapped drives, and if so, are you executing from an elevated powershell session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CIM_LogicalDisk` returns both local and mapped logical disk objects. You can match on the `Win32_LogicalDisk` or `CIM_LogicalDisk` types like so:

```
$Provider = Get-CimInstance CIM_LogicalDisk | Where-Object {
  $_.Name -eq 'W:' -And $_.CimClass.CimClassName -match '^(CIM|Win32)_LogicalDisk$'
}
```

This should omit the `Win32_MappedLogicalDisk` object from `$Provider`.

As for your question about no `CIM` cmdlets on Posh in Linux, [this Powershell Github issue from April](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6248#issuecomment-382679853) states, "There are no plans to port the CIM cmdlets to non-Windows."